# Google Drive export doc to html fails to export URLs

Tags: google-drive-api

When I export a document to HTML via the Java API, I can parse the output and everything looks fine, *except* any images in the document that contain URL links do NOT export the link.

For example, I add an image to a doc, select the image, hit the 'add link' button, and the doc appears to support the link. But when I export the doc to html that link is nowhere to be found.

I would expect to see it in the HTML as:

```
<a href="http://mylink"> <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/blahblahblah"> </a>
```

But instead just the IMG tag appears with no A HREF tag.

This doc for the LINK_URL property makes it sound like only text-based links are officially supported: [Google Apps Script Enum Attribute](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute):

> LINK_URL : The link URL, **for rich text**. The default link style (foreground color, underline) is automatically applied.

Any word from Google if there is a plan to support exporting image links?

Comment: This issue [appears to be happening in the UI as well](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/F_MVQNhdG5U), not just the API. I don't think there are any workarounds.